# Which of these sentences is better?

Tags: differences, word-order

> The user is redirected to your web page after the click.
>
> After the click, the user is redirected to your web page.

Which kind of sentence should be used, the first, the second, or neither?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both sentences are valid English.  The first emphasises the act of redirection, the second emphasises the cause (the click); it's entirely a matter of context as to which you should use.  The emphasis is fairly mild in this case, so feel free to choose either.

The phrase "After the click" sounds very slightly off to me.  I think I would normally say "After clicking" instead, since it is the act of clicking that is what we're really interested in.

Comment: +1 You made a good point that I missed - `After clicking` is preferred to `After the click`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any *musts* in this case - it a question of style. Personally, I prefer the second of your alternatives, but equally, there are a dozen other perfectly acceptable ways of conveying the same message.

> Clicking on the link redirects the user to your web page

or

> The user will be redirected to your web page when they click on the link

ad infinitum...

Answer (score 1):

Either are acceptable, but passive voice can be a trifle static sounding. I like @CJM's suggestion of

> Clicking on the link redirects the
>   user to your web page

because it's a bit more active.

Comment: Which one of my sentences is active and passive? I really don+t quite grasp the concept. thanks

Comment: @donald: they both are.  Passive voice is when you use 'to be' or 'to get' with the (usually) past participle of a transitive verb. e.g. *is* redirected. Here is the wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice

Comment: Either **are** acceptable?

Comment: @Kris: no need to be arch. Just edit it.

Comment: Why would I? You could be right, after all, in your opinion -- or do you take for granted that any one who finds your mistakes will edit them? Amazing! By the way, what's *arch.*? -- always avoid obscure abbreviations on ELU.

Comment: arch is not an abbreviation.  If you want a fight go elsewhere.